# importing data from excel getting empty rows also

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am trying to import data from excel file using this code block, which I got from a website.

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable(this ExcelPackage package)
        {
            ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            foreach (var firstRowCell in workSheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, workSheet.Dimension.End.Column])
            {
                table.Columns.Add(firstRowCell.Text);
            }
            var temp = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
            for (var rowNumber = 2; rowNumber <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Row; rowNumber++)
            {
                var row = workSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1, rowNumber, workSheet.Dimension.End.Column];
                var newRow = table.NewRow();
                foreach (var cell in row)
                {
                    newRow[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                }
                table.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
            return table;
        }
```

Suppose I have 10 rows of data in the excel file, later on I deleted 4 rows of data and save the file. Now when I import this excel file I get the rows count as 10 but it should be 6. Because there are only 6 rows of data. Why is it so?

```
var temp = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
```

How can I solve this problem in the code? Please help. Thank You!

Comment: You are skipping rows when you are deleting.   Whenever you delete anything start at end and move toward beginning.  Suppose you have rows 4,5,6.  When you delete row 5 then row 6 becomes row 5.  So use a loop like for(int rowNumber =  rowNumber <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Row; rowNumber >= 0; rowNumber--)

Comment: @jdweng I could not understand your reply properly `for(int rowNumber = rowNumber <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Row; rowNumber >= 0; rowNumber--)`. What is the initial value in this `for loop` ?

Comment: The code starts at the last row of data and then enumerates down to zero.  There was a typo in code : for(int rowNumber = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row; rowNumber >= 2; rowNumber--)